# PDO MYSQL Why not working?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I don't have any idea why it is not working any help ? :)

this returns 0;

```
$stmt3=$db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) as "ilosc" FROM plat_user WHERE `imie`="'.$_POST['imie'].'" AND `nazwisko`="'.$_POST['nazwisko'].'" AND `nip`="'.$_POST['nip'].'" AND `email`="'.$_POST['email'].'" AND `grupa`=1');
$stmt3->execute();
$row3 = $stmt3->fetch();
echo $row3['ilosc'];
```

this code works and (return 1):

```
$rowy = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) as "ilosc" FROM plat_user WHERE `imie`="'.$_POST['imie'].'" AND `nazwisko`="'.$_POST['nazwisko'].'" AND `nip`="'.$_POST['nip'].'" AND `email`="'.$_POST['email'].'" AND `grupa`=1'));
```

Generated query is good in phpmyadmin it return 1 i dont know why PDO return 0

Comment: `SELECT COUNT()` will always return 1 row, but the value of the count may be zero, so what's the actual problem here? Have you considered logging the SQL generated, and validating that manually?

Comment: Your `AS` syntax is wrong. Wrap table and column names in backticks, not quotes.

Comment: in mysql that query return 1 which is good but in PDO that query return 0 and don' now why.

Comment: Both code snippets also have SQL injection vulnerabilities. Read up on this site, or on the web generally, as to how to fix that.

Comment: Some debugging is required here. It is a good idea to create the SQL as a separate string variable `$sql` and then executing it, so you can also echo it if you wish. Please do that now, and present in your question what the SQL is.

Comment: Yes i know that, originally it is PDO prepare and bindParam

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) as "ilosc" FROM plat_user WHERE `imie`="data" AND `nazwisko`="data" AND `nip`="6381807598" AND `email`="test@test.pl" AND `grupa`=1
that sql return 1 in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

Just try it:

```
$stmt3=$db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) as "ilosc" FROM plat_user WHERE `imie`="'.$_POST['imie'].'" AND `nazwisko`="'.$_POST['nazwisko'].'" AND `nip`="'.$_POST['nip'].'" AND `email`="'.$_POST['email'].'" AND `grupa`=1');
$stmt3->execute();
$row3 = $stmt3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // changes here
echo $row3['ilosc'];
```